# How to remove rows from pandas dataframe with an initial date condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, valueerror

I have a pandas dataframe, one of the columns of which contains dates.

My objective is to set an initial date, **and discard all the rows of the dataframe that are previous to this date**.
Snippet of dataframe:

```py
 ID         fecha         
519457    25/02/2020 10:03    
519462    25/02/2020 10:07     
519468    25/02/2020 10:12
 ...           ...
```

The code I have been trying to use is the following:

```py
xls=pd.ExcelFile(r'/home/.../Final.xlsx')
xls.sheet_names
df=pd.read_excel(xls,"Hoja1")
Date_initial=['25/02/2020 10:07:00']
df=df.drop(df[["fecha"]<Date_initial].index)
```

Which did not work.
I also tried substituing the last line for:

```
df[(df['fecha']>=Date_initial)]
```

As a result, I obtained the error:

```
ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
```

Am I missing something in the expression, or going in a completely wrong way to doing this?
Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like this:

```
Date_initial='25/02/2020 10:07:00'
df=df[df["fecha"]>=Date_initial]]
```

Also, I recommend using `datetime` type:

```
df = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Hoja1', parse_dates=['fecha'], dayfirst=True)

Date_initial = pd.to_datetime('25/02/2020 10:07:00')
df = df[df['fecha'] >= Date_initial]
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks a lot.
PS. I removed an extra bracket from your answer.